# Prove that the inner product of continuous functions is a non-degenerate symmetric form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

Put $V$ as the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. I want to show that the symmetric form
$$ b:V\times V\to \mathbb{R},\left(f,g\right)\mapsto \int^1_0f(t)g(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
is non-degenerate. Put $r_b:V\to V^*,r_b(g)(f)=b(f,g)$, where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$, then $r_b$ is injective, since its kernal is obviously $0$. But how can I prove that $r_b$ is surjective? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Is $V$ endowed with the norm $f \mapsto \sqrt{b(f,f)}$?

Comment: @Gerd No, we just consider $V$ as a vector space.

Comment: So, what is $V^\ast$? Set of all linear functionals? Then $r_b$ is not surjective, since you can't generate the functional $f \mapsto f(0)$.

Comment: @Gerd Yes, $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$, namely the set of all linear forms.

Comment: So $r_b$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Gerd But why there is no such functional that maps $f$ to $f(0)$? Could you explain it in detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is some $g \in V:=C([0,1])$ such that
$$
\forall f \in V: \int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt=f(0).
$$
Then clearly $g \not=0$, hence (since $g$ is continuous) there is some interval $I:=[\alpha, \beta] \subseteq (0,1)$ such that $g(t) \not= 0$ $(t \in I)$. Hence $g$ has constant sign on $I$. Now choose any function $f \in V$ with $f(t) > 0$ on $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $f(t)=0$ outside $(\alpha,\beta)$.
Then
$$
0\not=\int_\alpha^\beta f(t)g(t)dt = \int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt = f(0)=0,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: ok I understand, thank you.